# Does the dynamic logic page at wikipedia have some mistakes?

Tags: modal-logic

I was reading about [dynamic logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_logic_%28modal_logic%29) over at wikipedia as a possible lead on a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490793/are-there-any-foundations-in-which-the-universe-itself-gets-dynamically-extended). However, its not making a lot of sense to me. In particular, wikipedia says that

> The constant action $0$ ... does nothing and does not terminate, whereas the constant action $1$ ... does nothing but does terminate.

That's fine, although its slightly odd that they refer to both $0$ and $1$ as "the constant action." I feel like only $0$ should be referred to as the constant action, since $1$ does something fairly drastic, in particular it terminates the program. Anyway, we then come to the following axiom

$$(A1) \;\;[0]p$$

which apparently reads, "it is necessary that if we enact the constant action that does nothing, then $p$ will hold," which seems like nonsense. We also have the following corollary

$$(T1) \neg \langle 0 \rangle p$$

which seems to be saying, "it's not possible that after performing the constant action that does nothing, we will observe that $p$ holds," which also sounds like nonsense.

So, I'm guessing that there's some mistakes on the wikipedia page. What are the correct conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally get it. When the page says "it does not terminate," the intended meaning is that the process $0$ never gets around to finishing. Thus, the statement $$[0]p$$

basically reads: "After the process that never gets around to finishing has finished, it is necessary that $p$ holds." This sounds completely reasonable.

So, the Wikipedia page is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have no prior knowledge of dynamic logic, but what you quote seems to fit together nicely.

"0" and "1" are "constant actions" in the sense that each is the *name* of one particular action which is the same action each time you mention the name. In other words, they are *constants* of type "action". That does not refer to what the actions they name actually do. (And the wording is arguably confusing, yes).

The axiom $[0]p$ effectively defines that 0 is *an action that it is always impossible to take*. What the axiom says that if you take it anyway, then anything will be true -- which is vacuously valid because you *can't take it*.

This is perhaps even clearer in the form $\neg\langle0\rangle p$, which directly says that "it is not possible to perform 0 and then have $p$ be true". If we let $p$ be the logical constant $\top$ (true), $\neg\langle0\rangle \top$ says neither more nor less than "it is not possible to perform 0".

Comment: Okay, but the quote says that: "0 ... does nothing and does not terminate." If it does nothing, why is it impossible to take?

Comment: @user18921: That quote seems to be an attempt to convey intuition, and evidently not doing it very well in your case. The formal _definition_ of what $0$ does is the axioms it satisfies, not how someone thought he could popularize it. --What is meant by "does nothing" must be that it doesn't say anything in particular about how the world before doing $0$ relates to the world after doing $0$, because there _is_ no world after doing $0$.

Comment: ... or perhaps better, $0$ "does nothing" in the sense that it doesn't lead to a world that differs from the world before you do $0$ -- but in contrast to $1$ (which does nothing because it always leads to the same world you started from), $0$ does nothing because it doesn't lead to _any_ world.

Comment: I certainly think you make a good point about $0$ being a "constant" action, in the same way that $e$ is a constant in the equational language of groups. However, I still think there is a mistake, either in the axioms or in the "intuition" part. Lets wait and see if someone with some experience in the field will post and clarify.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I get it now. $0$ is the action that "runs forever" and never gets around to terminating. So you were right, there is no mistake on the wikipedia page.